# Want to install six and It gives me the error " No module named 'six' "

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, six

I get following error:

```
fhem@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads$ sudo pip install six-1.10.0.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Thx for all answers!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py`? It's strange that pip it's trying to import a global version of it

Comment: Never changed anything there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to untar the tar file.

```
tar -xzvf ./six-1.10.0.tar.gz
```

Then cd into six-1.10.0

Then install using -

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: This does work, but it's not *essential* -- pip *can* install from a downloaded file, just not with the syntax the OP was originally trying to use.

Comment: ok that installation worked but others still dont work... fhem@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/attr-0.2.0$ sudo pip install attr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'

Comment: sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip             Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify six version in other way, as `six==1.10.0`, command below would work for you:

```
sudo pip install six==1.10.0
```